# Building "floor switcher" toggle button in Web AppBuilder for ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder

I've been trying to make a Floor Switcher for my web app in WAB. There is one MapService of my building which i could simple query (layer.setDefinitionExpression("exp")) based on attribute. In-panel widget isn't a good solution because i want to change floors without open any panel. Simple toggle buttons or node list directly in app view will be the best solution.

I found these two topics, one with toggle button, but i don't know is it possible to implement this in WAB app.
[How do I use a toggle button with the ESRI javascript api](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24315)
Second one is that what i'm looking for but unfortunately in panel widget, so isn't very user-friendly.
https://geonet.esri.com/thread/158023

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use Web AppBuilder? In the ArcGIS Online Scene Viewer, there is an option to toggle layers.

Comment: Hi, but the goal is to have only one floor layer switched on at the time (also in layer list). So one click switches on only one layer and switches off the rest. If that makes sense.

Comment: Take a look at the [GIS facilities templates](http://www.esri.com/industries/government/facilities/templates)

Comment: Specifically the [campus place locator map](http://solutions.arcgis.com/local-government/help/campus-place-locator/) - try it [live](http://tryitlive.arcgis.com/CampusPlaceLocator/index.html)

Comment: I think that will do the trick. Cheers!

Comment: @MDHald: if the OP said it helped, could you expand your comment into an answer, so that this question can get properly "answered" (no longer appearing in "not answered" tab)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Campus Place Locator Map](http://solutions.arcgis.com/local-government/help/campus-place-locator/) from ESRI outlines how to map multiple stories in GIS.

Try it Live:

[image]